# Understanding on concept of IAM role on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm just getting in touch with EC2 and came across the IAM Role concept. This question is to clear my doubt about the concept on restriction level.

Lets say I have an `EC2` instance with attached IAM Role `Role A` which posses one policy `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess`, correct me if i'm wrong but it means this particular instance **only allow to perform S3 Read only operation**.

Now says I created a `User` with `Programmatic access` and `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy.

If this user SSH into the EC2 instance, can he write file to `s3` ?

I still unable to try it out by myself as I don't have a linux machine and still figuring on how to connect to `Ec2` using `putty`

Comment: If you want to connect to EC2 linux machine http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lets say I have an EC2 instance with attached IAM Role Role A which
>   posses one policy AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess, correct me if i'm wrong but
>   it means this particular instance only allow to perform S3 Read only
>   operation.

Yes

> Now says I created a User with Programmatic access and
>   AmazonS3FullAccess policy. If this user SSH into the EC2 instance, can
>   he write file to s3 ?

IAM users cannot SSH to EC2 instances using IAM user credentials. After provisioning a EC2 instance, you need to use regular Operating System User constructs, to SSH to the Server (Default user keys created by AWS).

In addition if a user SSH to EC2 instance and use a Programatic Access Credentials of a EC2 User through AWS CLI, REST API or SDKs (Doesn't have to be a EC2 instance, it also can be your on-premise server) then if the IAM User has a S3 write policy, the CLI commands or API calls or the code using SDK is able to write files to S3.

So in a summary

- Use IAM roles if you are running a EC2 instance, for your CLI commands, Code with SDK, or REST API calls to access AWS Resources.
- If you are using a server on-premise or outside AWS, use IAM User's Programatic Access keys to do the same.

Insight on how IAM roles work internally with EC2

- When you attach a IAM role to a EC2 instance, AWS periodically updates the EC2 instance with temporal Access Credentials to that EC2 instance (Which is a good security practice).
- These credentials are accessible through the Metadata URLs for the CLI, REST API and Code using SDKs inside EC2 instance.

Note: When using Roles, its much secure since it uses Temporal access credentials vs IAM Users Programatic Access uses Long lived access credentials.

Comment: so is it means that after this user accessed `EC2` via `AWS CLI`, `AWS` will   value the policy of the user more despite the fact that this user is on this particular EC2 instance that only has a read access

Comment: When you say "This user accessed" means OS user in EC2 or IAM user? Note: Only OS user SSH to the EC2 instance. When the OS user SSH to the EC2 instance, if there is a Role attached to the EC2 instance, all the CLI commands uses that role to access resources such as S3. So for this operation IAM User is not required (Only IAM role is sufficient). Check the answer summary at the end.

Comment: My scenario is, I will first using OS user SSH to EC2 instance and configure a user profile for the user I've created.

Comment: Is the answer clear @Mr.SuicideSheep? I just updated the answer with insights for more clarifications.

Comment: According to your answer **then if the IAM User has a S3 write policy, the CLI commands or API calls or the code using SDK is able to write files to S3.** which means will ignore the role policy that attached to this EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, if you configure your EC2 instance to use a IAM user's credentials for CLI, SDK or REST API (Don't do it, use a Role which is better, as mentioned in the answer) then it will use its policy. Use a Role policy instead.